# Connect two batteries in parallel with transistors?

Tags: transistors, batteries

I am trying to figure out how I can connect two small 12V lead acid batteries in parallel using transistors, but when testing this circuit on the breadboard, the voltages didn't equalize so that tells me the two batteries weren't connected to each other.

How could I make what I am wanting to accomplish?

The bases in the schematic will be pulled low by another transistor when a certain condition is met in the microcontroller, thus isolating the batteries.

The goal is for the microcontroller and other circuitry to be running off of the BT2 battery when a motor causes a voltage drop from BT1, and when the motor is turned off, the batteries are normally connected together increasing the capacity of the system.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Like I said, connect two batteries in parallel with transistors..

Comment: Why? Why not a wire?  What do you expect the transistors to do for you?

Comment: There is a point where the two batteries need to be disconnected without human intervention so I need the transistors.

Comment: Ah, OK, this wasn't clear from your question.  How will the transistors be controlled?  Your drawing doesn't seem to allow for any external control, as a relay would.

Comment: The bases would be pulled low by another transistor elsewhere in the schematic.

Comment: OK you edited your last comment - 'without human intervention' - so when do you expect the circuit to disconnect or reconnect?

Comment: See my last comment

Comment: The bases will be at the same voltage as the respective emitters, so they will not turn on.

Comment: I edited my question to give more detail of the purpose this is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better off doing this with MOSFETs.  There are two back to back because otherwise the body diode would cause flow from one battery to the other.

When you apply some voltage to R1 from your MCU, Q1 will pull the gates of Q2 and Q3 low, turning them on, so current will be allowed to flow in either direction.  When Q1 is off, all transistors will turn off and the two batteries will be isolated.

The R2 pull-up assumes that V1 is the primary source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpoJHh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also try this.  It uses a singe PNP BJT instead so it's simpler but the transistor may dissipate more power than the MOSFETs.  You may also run into issues if the voltage differences are high, but I think it would work for you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv56Xs.png)</sup>

Comment: Will this allow the batteries to equalize each other when the NPN transistor is turned on? I do want the two batteries currents to flow to and from each other most of the time because the motor is off most of the time.

Comment: Yes when turned on they will both conduct in either direction.

Comment: Thanks. Are Q2 and Q3 both P channel FETs?

Comment: Yes, both P-ch, and you would want to make sure they can handle Vgs of at least the max battery voltage.  Most will take up to +/-20V so this should be fine.  If the batteries are higher voltage you would need to modify this.

Comment: When Q1 is turned off, when the batteries want to equalize with each other, will this current in-rush destroy Q2 or Q3?

Comment: It depends on the internal resistance of the batteries, the ratings of the transistors, and how long that equalization takes.  It is possible to blow the FETs if they are underrated.

Comment: Circuit two with the PNP BJT didn't work. I don't see how current can flow in both directions with that circuit either.

Comment: Current will flow 'backward' through the transistor, but they are not commonly used this way.  What components are you using?  I did a quick simulation with some generic (with 10V and 12V on each battery, and then swapped) and it worked OK.  Th voltage drop was higher than I expected, but again I think that could be fixed with proper component selection.

Comment: I used a TIP42C PNP transistor, pretty common.

Comment: What about the resistors and NPN?  Also, what are the node voltages?  Particularly Vbe of both transistors.

Comment: I used a 10K resistor and no NPN, since I just wanted to test I pulled the base low manually with a jumper to no avail.

Comment: 10k might not allow enough base current.  The TIP42 is not a very high gain transistor, so you might only be seeing 50mA or so.  Try a lower value resistor.

Comment: I am confused, it is a PNP transistor, so when the base is grounded out it should turn on? I was pulling the base to ground at the junction of the base and resistor. I believe the resistor is used to keep the transistor off (pull-up)

Comment: Q1 is PNP and Q2 is NPN.  Q1 would require current OUT from the base to turn on (as opposed to an NPN requiring current into the base).  Pulling the base low allows current to flow out of the base, up to the point where the voltage from base to emitter (Vbe) is about -0.7V, or said another way, the voltage from the emitter to the base would be about +0.7V.  Q2 is there to pull the base low (to turn it on) but the resistor is there to prevent the Vbe voltage going to far and the current exceeding the transistor limit.  If you pulled the base directly to ground it may have damaged the PNP.

Comment: There is no pull-ups in this circuit.  I generally don't use them for BJTs, as you would normally do for MOSFETs which are voltage controlled.  You could still add pull-ups or pull-downs if you want, but again neither of the resistors in the schematic serve that purpose.  They are both to limit base current.

Comment: It worked with the PNP; I had to use a 100 ohm resistor and you were right, the PNPs were destroyed from the earlier tests. I think it'll be easier to use a dual P channel FET in this case.